# Can I change the style of Facebook and Twitter share buttons

Tags: css, facebook, twitter

So when i'm using Twitter and Facebook share functionality I get the default share buttons that look like:
[image: Facebook Share]
[image: Twitter Share]

I read the policies and it states:`Don't obscure or cover elements of social plugins.` Am I allowed to style the button?

Instead of the default? Or is this against the Facebook/Twitters Policies?

Comment: Original social buttons are so difficult to layout that is doesn't even funny. I'm starting to remove them all from my sites.

Answer (score 5):

Just build your own in HTML and CSS. It’s really easy. Just make html links and design them with CSS. Put the Icon in it and ready. The URL for Sharing in Facebook is the following:

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[URL]
```

And for Twitter it is:

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=[TITLE]&url=[URL]&via=[USER]
```

All Things in brackets [] are Things you should fill in (manually or via PHP/JS). The URL should be clear. The TITLE is the text for Twitter to Show with the tweet and the USER is the Name Twitter Shows in the tweet. Like this »Some page title [URL] via **@kaiserkiwi**«

Answer (score 1):

[Facebook Do's and Don'ts](https://www.facebookbrand.com/dos-donts):

> ***Don'ts***
>
> - Modify Facebook brand assets in any way, such as by changing the
>     design or color

---

[Twitter Usage Guidelines](https://about.twitter.com/company/brand-assets)

> Always use our official and unmodified Twitter logo to represent
>   Twitter.

That said, Facebook and Twitter logos are highly modified on thousands of web pages across the web. I think as long as you make your modifications elegant, professional and attractive, you won't face any enforcement action.

If they do contact you, they'll likely start with a *cease and desist* notice. At that point you can remove your modified logos and the enforcement measures normally stop.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this. The difficult way is to read lots of Twitter and Facebook documentation and use that to create something of your own. The easy way is to use third party tools like AddThis. You can easily customise buttons in any way you like. If you're using WordPress, [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/addthis/) is their plugin. You can also use ShareThis and their WordPress [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/share-this/). With ShareThis you can use their native CSS classes to overwrite default look and feel. For example, after you install the plugin, choose custom option and then you can target the following classes: .st_twitter_custom and .st_facebook_custom. Hope, this helps.